# Styling a background image. Wordpress, php.

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

I'm using Wordpress and I'm currently trying to add a width to an image that's being brought in as a background image, but I can't seem to do so...

The image is  at the top of the page here: http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/brand/ I have the text working the way I would like (centre and middle by using vertical align and a dimply:table; and table cell), the the image in the background seems to be full size but I would like to make it the same width as the container it is a background of...

For reference, the full image looks like this:

[image]

Im using the page's Featured Image, so to enable this to be pulled into the background, I've had to use some PHP, so here's the code displaying the image and the text:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {

    // Get the post thumbnail URL
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
  } else {

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">.featured-image{
    display:none;
    }</style>
    <?php
  } ?>


    <div id="absolute1111" style=" background: url(<?php echo $feat_image; ?>);">
        <div class="centerd1111">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My styles are as follows:

```
#absolute1111 {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    display:table;
    color: #fff;
}

.centerd1111 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    height:500px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}
```

Hopefully someone will be able to help :) Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this is what you would like:

```
#absolute1111 {
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   height:50%;
   display:table;
   color: #fff;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: #274c55;
   background-position-x: 50%; # See comments below about standards
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Comment: `background-position-x` is not standard, it doesn't work on firefox. Use `background-position` instead

Comment: You are welcome! `background-position-[x|y]` is a google invention, nothing standard. It works on webkit, but it's better to use standards to reuse one code to all browsers, avoiding unnecessary fallbacks

Comment: Thanks for this - I have added the code ass suggested but it still doesn't seem to be working? I even tried removing the X from background-position: 50%; but it doesn't seem to effect anything?

Comment: Ok, so putting a few  !important statement in there effected it, but if you look now, its not reaching the edges - I would like it to be 100% width of the page but the height to go up and down as the page gets smaller...

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments - Changing contain to cover seems to work better - I now just have to adjust the height :) Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that the height is tricky and will not always display right on different screen widths / resolutions. Just test them out.

Comment: Hi Again @jeremy - Sorry to come back, but would you know how I can adjust the height for this? http://ideedev.co.uk/newseed/design/ I ideally want to make it less hight for smaller devices. I know how to use media queries but I'm unsure which CSS I need to edit after playing with it?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit unclear. i think you can add following to css:

```
#absolute1111 {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    display:table;
    color: #fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```